# UNET: Синхронизированная переменная

Tags: c#, unity3d, сеть

Доброго времени суток. Мне понадобилось реализовать, чтобы после нажатия кнопки на сервере менялась буловая переменная `Status[n]`, которая показывает готов ли наш пользователь к началу игры. Т.е. переменная должна хранится только на сервере, как я понимаю. Но вот не совсем понятно, создав скрипт, который должен хранить эту переменную, то саму переменную надо обозначать атрибутом `[SyncVar]`, и к объекту, на котором будет скрипт -- надо добавить `NetworkIdentity`. А так просто такой объект на сцену не добавишь. Можно ли как-то проще организовать, чтобы на сервере мы хранили единственный экземпляр переменной, а клиент его значение мог менять?

P.S. у меня всего один префаб со скриптом наследующим `NetoworkBehaviour` и имеющий `NetworkIdentity` -- префаб игрока. Класс сервера наследуется от `MonoBehavior`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таком случае используйте [`NetworkMessage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/UNetMessages.html) для отправки изменений переменной на сервер отдельным пакетом. И в случае необходимости отсылайте их другим клиентам с сервера.

Comment: А как отправить переменную клиентам? У мессанджей тип void. И где/как эту переменную хранить?

Comment: @Pepsi4 почитайте примеры документации https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/UNetMessages.html . Чтобы пересылать данные делаете наследника от `MessageBase`, в нем задаете все необходимые для передачи параметры. Также создаете `Enum` с перечислением всех ваших пакетов, а дальше с сервера делаете рассылку параметров всем адресатам через один из методов, например так `NetworkServer.SendToAll(MyMsgType.Score, msg);`. Здесь первый параметр это тип сообщения, а второй собственно ваш объект наследник `MessageBase` с установленными параметрами. Одним словом посмотрите пример кода в оф. справке.